# How do I create an acknowledgment section?

Tags: sectioning

I am trying to add an acknowledgment section like. I have tried the 'acknowledgments' and 'acknowledgements' environments (as seen on the internet), but LaTeX did not recognized it.

Comment: What document class are you using? If they're not recognized it's probably because you're using a document class where they're not defined.

Comment: I'm using `report` class. The document is a master thesis. Is there any better class?

Answer (score 25):

Most classes don't provide a environment for the acknowledgements. I do my acknowledgements for my thesis the following way:

```
\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\thispagestyle{empty}

I like to acknowledge ...

\clearpage
```

This adds a chapter-like headline without number on a page of its own. I like to also not have a page number for it. Afterwards flush the page using a `\clearpage`, just to be on the safe side.

If you writing a paper or other article-like document use `\section*` instead of `\chapter*` and skip the other commands.

Answer (score 12):

In a chapter based document:

```
\cleardoublepage% especially in a document where chapters start at right-hand pages
\phantomsection% for an anchor if you use hyperref
\addtocontents{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements}% if you wish to have a TOC entry
\chapter*{Acknowledgements}% for the actuall unnumbered heading
\thispagestyle{empty}% or plain etc.
\markboth{Acknowledgements}{Acknowledgements}% relevant depending on page style
    % or if it's more than one page
```

Similar with `\section*`, if required as section. Omit lines above which you don't need.

Here you might see, a macro name for *Acknowledgements* could be good, and using that, i.e.

```
\newcommand*{\ackname}{Acknowledgements}
```

Comment: I want to put my Acknowledgement just before the TOC. Then where should I put these codes and which environment should I use? book or report?

Comment: @Ome Then put this code before `\tableofcontents`. `report` is usually a good choice, `book` is more book-like, default settings are different. You can switch between them at any time to see, how the layout changes.

Answer (score 2):

```
\section*{Acknowledgement}

I offer my sincerest gratitude to my right arm, .....

In a chapter-based document, simply use:

\chapter*{Acknowledgement}

I offer my sincerest gratitude to my right arm, .....
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please explain what your code does in your answer! And how it solves the given issue ... And no, I did not downvote your answer!