# Showcase of beautiful title page done in TeX

Tags: titles, typography, big-list

The book is mostly meets by the Title Page. Default TeX `\maketitle` are simple and minimalistic.

I'm looking for examples of Title Pages:

- complex - have different formatting;
- beautiful and awesome;
- available online;
- and, finally!, with TeX sources available.

I think such examples would be a great inspiration and motivation stuff!

Comment: The document »[Some Examples of Title Pages](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlepages)« might be helpful here.

Comment: I think Thorsten Donig's comment makes a good answer and I'd vote it up.

Comment: Similar: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17579/how-can-i-design-a-book-cover

Comment: See: http://www.latextemplates.com/cat/title-pages

Comment: @ChristianLindig: Here you are.

Comment: I believe that if you want this to be really a _showcase_, it should be a [Community Wiki](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/480/what-does-community-wiki-mean) question.

Comment: Have a look a t [Vincent Zoonekynd's title pages](http://zoonek.free.fr/LaTeX/LaTeX_samples_title/0.html).

Answer (score 133, accepted):

In answer to the question [Creating a titlepage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/85870/10898), Harish Kumar and azetina provided the following nice title page:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,demo]{report} %% Remove demo in your file.
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}% Used for dummy text.
\definecolor{titlepagecolor}{cmyk}{1,.60,0,.40}
\definecolor{namecolor}{cmyk}{1,.50,0,.10} 
%-----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{titlepage}
\newgeometry{left=7.5cm} %defines the geometry for the titlepage
\pagecolor{titlepagecolor}
\noindent
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{logo.jpg}\\[-1em]
\color{white}
\makebox[0pt][l]{\rule{1.3\textwidth}{1pt}}
\par
\noindent
\textbf{\textsf{UniversitätsKlinikum}} \textcolor{namecolor}{\textsf{Heidelberg}}
\vfill
\noindent
{\huge \textsf{Handbuch 1.3}}
\vskip\baselineskip
\noindent
\textsf{August 2008}
\end{titlepage}
\restoregeometry % restores the geometry
\nopagecolor% Use this to restore the color pages to white
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\lipsum[1-9]
\end{document}
```

Here is another example:

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[some]{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{titlepagecolor}{cmyk}{1,.60,0,.40}

\backgroundsetup{
scale=1,
angle=0,
opacity=1,
contents={\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
 \path [fill=titlepagecolor] (current page.west)rectangle (current page.north east); 
 \draw [color=white, very thick] (5,0)--(5,0.5\paperheight);
\end{tikzpicture}}
}

\makeatletter                   
\def\printauthor{%                  
    {\large \@author}}          
\makeatother

\author{%
    Author 1 name \\
    Department name \\
    \texttt{email1@example.com}\vspace{40pt} \\
    Author 2 name \\
    Department name \\
    \texttt{email2@example.com}
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\BgThispage
\newgeometry{left=1cm,right=6cm,bottom=2cm}
\vspace*{0.4\textheight}
\noindent
\textcolor{white}{\Huge\textbf{\textsf{Hardy's Theorem}}}
\vspace*{2cm}\par
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.35\linewidth}
    \begin{flushright}
        \printauthor
    \end{flushright}
\end{minipage} \hspace{15pt}
%
\begin{minipage}{0.02\linewidth}
    \rule{1pt}{175pt}
\end{minipage} \hspace{-10pt}
%
\begin{minipage}{0.63\linewidth}
\vspace{5pt}
    \begin{abstract} 
An abstract is a brief summary of a research article, thesis, review, conference proceeding or any in-depth analysis of a particular subject or discipline, and is often used to help the reader quickly ascertain the paper's purpose. When used, an abstract always appears at the beginning of a manuscript, acting as the point-of-entry for any given scientific paper or patent application. Abstracting and indexing services for various academic disciplines are aimed at compiling a body of literature for that particular subject.
    \end{abstract}
\end{minipage}
\end{titlepage}
\restoregeometry
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

Yet another flavor:

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[some]{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{titlepagecolor}{cmyk}{1,.60,0,.40}

\DeclareFixedFont{\bigsf}{T1}{phv}{b}{n}{1.5cm}

\backgroundsetup{
scale=1,
angle=0,
opacity=1,
contents={\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
 \path [fill=titlepagecolor] (-0.5\paperwidth,5) rectangle (0.5\paperwidth,10);  
\end{tikzpicture}}
}
\makeatletter                       
\def\printauthor{%                  
    {\large \@author}}              
\makeatother
\author{%
    Author 1 name \\
    Department name \\
    \texttt{email1@example.com}\vspace{40pt} \\
    Author 2 name \\
    Department name \\
    \texttt{email2@example.com}
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\BgThispage
\newgeometry{left=1cm,right=4cm}
\vspace*{2cm}
\noindent
\textcolor{white}{\bigsf Hardy's Theorem}
\vspace*{2.5cm}\par
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.35\linewidth}
    \begin{flushright}
        \printauthor
    \end{flushright}
\end{minipage} \hspace{15pt}
%
\begin{minipage}{0.02\linewidth}
    \rule{1pt}{175pt}
\end{minipage} \hspace{-10pt}
%
\begin{minipage}{0.6\linewidth}
\vspace{5pt}
    \begin{abstract} 
An abstract is a brief summary of a research article, thesis, review, conference proceeding or any in-depth analysis of a particular subject or discipline, and is often used to help the reader quickly ascertain the paper's purpose. When used, an abstract always appears at the beginning of a manuscript, acting as the point-of-entry for any given scientific paper or patent application. Abstracting and indexing services for various academic disciplines are aimed at compiling a body of literature for that particular subject.
    \end{abstract}
\end{minipage}
\end{titlepage}
\restoregeometry
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

Yet another example (using code from [Trying to do graphical decorations in "ClassicThesis style"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86294/trying-to-do-graphical-decorations-in-classicthesis-style/86310#86310)):

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand\epigraphflush{flushright}
\renewcommand\epigraphsize{\normalsize}
\setlength\epigraphwidth{0.7\textwidth}

\definecolor{titlepagecolor}{cmyk}{1,.60,0,.40}

\DeclareFixedFont{\titlefont}{T1}{ppl}{b}{it}{0.5in}

\makeatletter                       
\def\printauthor{%                  
    {\large \@author}}              
\makeatother
\author{%
    Author 1 name \\
    Department name \\
    \texttt{email1@example.com}\vspace{20pt} \\
    Author 2 name \\
    Department name \\
    \texttt{email2@example.com}
    }

% The following code is borrowed from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86310/10898

\newcommand\titlepagedecoration{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,shorten >= -10pt]

\coordinate (aux1) at ([yshift=-15pt]current page.north east);
\coordinate (aux2) at ([yshift=-410pt]current page.north east);
\coordinate (aux3) at ([xshift=-4.5cm]current page.north east);
\coordinate (aux4) at ([yshift=-150pt]current page.north east);

\begin{scope}[titlepagecolor!40,line width=12pt,rounded corners=12pt]
\draw
  (aux1) -- coordinate (a)
  ++(225:5) --
  ++(-45:5.1) coordinate (b);
\draw[shorten <= -10pt]
  (aux3) --
  (a) --
  (aux1);
\draw[opacity=0.6,titlepagecolor,shorten <= -10pt]
  (b) --
  ++(225:2.2) --
  ++(-45:2.2);
\end{scope}
\draw[titlepagecolor,line width=8pt,rounded corners=8pt,shorten <= -10pt]
  (aux4) --
  ++(225:0.8) --
  ++(-45:0.8);
\begin{scope}[titlepagecolor!70,line width=6pt,rounded corners=8pt]
\draw[shorten <= -10pt]
  (aux2) --
  ++(225:3) coordinate[pos=0.45] (c) --
  ++(-45:3.1);
\draw
  (aux2) --
  (c) --
  ++(135:2.5) --
  ++(45:2.5) --
  ++(-45:2.5) coordinate[pos=0.3] (d);   
\draw 
  (d) -- +(45:1);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}

\noindent
\titlefont Hardy's Theorem\par
\epigraph{Pure mathematics is on the whole distinctly more useful than applied. For what is useful above all is technique, and mathematical technique is taught mainly through pure mathematics.}%
{\textit{London 1941}\\ \textsc{G. H. Hardy}}
\null\vfill
\vspace*{1cm}
\noindent
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.35\linewidth}
    \begin{flushright}
        \printauthor
    \end{flushright}
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}{0.02\linewidth}
    \rule{1pt}{125pt}
\end{minipage}
\titlepagedecoration
\end{titlepage}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

You can find other examples at: http://www.latextemplates.com/cat/title-pages

Comment: For the first template: I have a question. The texts starts right from the next page of the cover/title page. How can I keep a blank page and a page for 'Acknowledgement' just after the cover page?

Comment: @Ome Take a look at this post: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25838/10898

Comment: @azetina do you know why I get \backgroundsetup undefined sequence even though I have background.sty? Does it require a newer version?

Comment: Found it here https://github.com/toonn/drunken-dangerzone/blob/master/NetworkSimulationPart2/background.sty

Comment: `abstract` is not defined for books, but you can change it for `quotation` environment.

Comment: Is there an easy way to mimic this decoration for the left side of the page?

Answer (score 40):

The question [LaTeX3 and pauper's coffins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44241/latex3-and-paupers-coffins) discusses various ways to implement a famous title page by Tschichold in LaTeX:

[image]

The picture above shows the various relationships that this design implements (the arrows are overlayed on a picture of the original).

The implementation (using expl3's coffin concepts) is given in [Is there no easier way to float objects and set margins?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44065/is-there-no-easier-way-to-float-objects-and-set-margins/44159#44159). The LaTeX3 reimplementation then gives this (without trying to use exactly the same fonts):

[image]

Comment: I like the Bauhaus-esque style.

Answer (score 37):

I find the titlepages of the ConTeXt manuals to be visually very pleasing. A few of them involve randomized elements. The source for some of the manuals is available [at this svn mirror](http://context.aanhet.net/svn/).

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

(Click on the images to see a bigger version)

Comment: At the beginning that was overwhelming to see but thanks for the smaller previews.

Comment: To me, these look more like covers than title pages, but they awesome nonetheless.

Answer (score 36):

My humble contribution- I made this for the, 'Program Review' that we have at our college. The background image it uses can be found [here](http://opportunity.pcc.edu/departmentbanners/), but of course you'll probably want to insert your own :)

The code uses the [`tcolorbox`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tcolorbox) and [`eso-pic`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/eso-pic) packages.

[image: screenshot]

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{eso-pic}                
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\tcbset{
    pccstyle/.style={
        enhanced,flushright upper,
        boxrule=1.4pt,
        colback=white,colframe=black!50!yellow,
        drop fuzzy midday shadow=black!50!yellow
    }
}

\AddToShipoutPicture{% from package eso-pic: put something to the background
    \AtPageCenter{% start the bar at the bottom right of the page
        \put(-\LenToUnit{.465\paperwidth},-\LenToUnit{.4\paperheight}){% move it to the middle
            %{\transparent{.5}{\includegraphics[width=20cm]{50th_mathematicsproof}}}
            \begin{tcolorbox}[pccstyle,left=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm]
                \includegraphics[width=20cm]{50th_mathematicsproof}
            \end{tcolorbox}
        }%
    }%
    \AtPageLowerLeft{% start the bar at the bottom right of the page
        \put(\LenToUnit{\dimexpr\paperwidth-3cm},0){% move it to the top right
            \color{blue}\rule{3cm}{\LenToUnit\paperheight}%
        }%
        \put(\LenToUnit{\dimexpr\paperwidth-2.7cm},\LenToUnit{17cm}){% move it to the top right
            \color{gray}\scalebox{8}{$\sum$}
        }%
        \put(\LenToUnit{\dimexpr\paperwidth-2.5cm},\LenToUnit{12.5cm}){% move it to the top right
            \color{gray}\scalebox{8}{$\int$}
        }%
        \put(\LenToUnit{\dimexpr\paperwidth-2.3cm},\LenToUnit{8.5cm}){% move it to the top right
            \color{gray}\scalebox{8}{$e$}
        }%
        \put(\LenToUnit{\dimexpr\paperwidth-2.7cm},\LenToUnit{5.0cm}){% move it to the top right
            \color{gray}\scalebox{8}{$\pi$}
        }%
        \put(\LenToUnit{\dimexpr\paperwidth-2.2cm},\LenToUnit{1.5cm}){% move it to the top right
            \color{gray}\scalebox{8}{$i$}
        }%
    }%
}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\vspace*{1cm}
\mbox{}\hfill\scalebox{2}{
    \begin{tcolorbox}[pccstyle,width=6.8cm]
        {\bfseries\LARGE {Program Review} \par}
        {\large \itshape Mathematics \par}
        {\large Portland Community College }
    \end{tcolorbox}
}

\vfill
\centering

\scalebox{2}{%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[pccstyle,width=4.8cm]
        {\scshape Fall 2008--Spring 2013}
    \end{tcolorbox}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please reupload the background image?

Comment: https://github.com/PCCMathProgramReview2014/PCCMathProgramReview2014/blob/master/graphics/50th_mathematicsproof.pdf

Answer (score 33):

This is an example derived from the document »[Some Examples of Title Pages](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlepages)«. It is not the most spectacular one but should be a good starting point.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newlength{\drop}

\begin{document}
  \begin{titlepage}
    \drop=0.1\textheight
    \centering
    \vspace*{\baselineskip}
    \rule{\textwidth}{1.6pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace*{2pt}
    \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\\[\baselineskip]
    {\LARGE CONUNDRUMS\\ AND \\[0.3\baselineskip] PUZZLES}\\[0.2\baselineskip]
    \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace{3.2pt}
    \rule{\textwidth}{1.6pt}\\[\baselineskip]
    \scshape
    Selected and Expanded Papers from the Organisation Working Conference on \\
    Enigmas \\
    Location, date from--to\par
    \vspace*{2\baselineskip}
    Edited by \\[\baselineskip]
    {\Large FIRST EDITOR \\ SECOND EDITOR \\ THIRD EDITOR\par}
    {\itshape Organisation \\ Address\par}
    \vfill
    {\scshape year} \\
    {\large THE PUBLISHER}\par
  \end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

In opposite to the document I did not define a command but simply put the necessary code into a [`titlepage`](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/latex2e-help-texinfo/latex2e.html#titlepage) environment.

The appendix Section A of the document has important information about all necessary stuff for creating the title pages.

---

[image]

Comment: A standard installation should have this document accessible via `texdoc titlepages`.

Comment: Thank you! This is beautiful and minimalistic, just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 23):

This is just my little collaboration. It's not as professional as some examples and the code is far from elegant. So feel free to edit/adapt and improve.

First a more traditional style. Many old books have a title page that look similar to this. I'v used tcolorbox and tikz with [`calligra`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/calligra?lang=en) font just for fancy.

[image: Booktitle with frame]

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% This template has been done collecting multiple entries from:
% http://tex.stackexchange.com
%
% Author:
% Graciano Bay
%
% License:
% CC BY-SA 3.0 (https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\documentclass[b4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,fit,chains,calc,scopes}            
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} %To compile psvectorian directly
\usepackage{psvectorian}
\renewcommand*{\psvectorianDefaultColor}{Green}%

\tcbset{
    Baystyle/.style={
        sharp corners,
        enhanced,
        boxrule=6pt,
        colframe=OliveGreen,
        height=\textheight,
        width=\textwidth,
        borderline={8pt}{-11pt}{},
    }
}



\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\centering
    \begin{tcolorbox}[Baystyle,]
        {\begin{center}
        \vspace*{0.14\textheight}
        \fontsize{45}{45}\scshape Book Title\\        
        \vspace*{0.018\textheight}
        \vspace*{0.2\textheight}
        % Big Logo\\
        \vspace*{0.2\textheight}
        {\fontsize{12}{12}\calligra A original story of\\}
        \fontsize{28}{28}\scshape Author Name\\
        \vspace*{0.1\textheight}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
        start chain=main going right,
          ]

             \node[on chain,align=center,draw=none] (a1){{\fontsize{12}{12}\calligra Illustrations by} \\
             {\Large Designer}
             }; 
             { [start branch=A going below]
             \node[on chain,align=center,draw=none,scale=0.01](d1){};
             \node[on chain,align=center,draw=none,](d2){\Huge Press logo};
             %\node[on chain,align=center,draw=none,scale=0.01](d3){};
             }
             \node[on chain,align=center,draw=none] (a2){\psvectorian[]{148}}; 
             { [start branch=B going below]
             \node[on chain,align=center,draw=none,scale=0.01](s1){};
             \node[on chain,align=center,draw=none,](s2){};
             %\node[on chain,align=center,draw=none,scale=0.01](s3){}; 
             }
             \node[on chain,align=center,draw=none]  (a3){{\fontsize{12}{12}\calligra Final review by} \\
             {\Large Revisor}
             };          
             { [start branch=C going below]
             \node[on chain,align=center,draw=none,scale=0.01](e1){};
             \node[on chain,align=center,draw=none,](e2){\Huge Other Logo};
             %\node[on chain,align=center,draw=none,scale=0.01](e3){}; 
        }
        \draw[black] (s2.north) -- (s2.south);
        \end{tikzpicture}
            \end{center}}
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

My second is certainly not classic looking. Here i've used only tikz.

[image: Blue Mark title page]

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% This template has been done collecting multiple entries from:
% http://tex.stackexchange.com
%
% Author:
% Graciano Bay
%
% License:
% CC BY-SA 3.0 (https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)
% 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\documentclass[b4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[margin=1cm,]{geometry}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
%\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{tikz}   
\usetikzlibrary{calc,scopes,positioning,backgrounds}            
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{microtype}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[local bounding box=picture, baseline=(picture.south)] 
        \node [draw=none] (A) at (0,0) {};
        \node [draw=none] (B) at (15,5) {};
        \node [draw=none] (C) at (5,-5) {};
        \foreach \s/\col in {1.5/ProcessBlue, 1/SkyBlue, 0/ProcessBlue}{
          \path [draw,\col, line width=40] ($(A.west)-(0,\s cm)$) to ($(C.west)-(0,\s cm)$) to ($(B.west)-(0,\s cm)$);
        }
        %
        \node [draw=none] (A2) at (0,-20) {};
                \node [draw=none] (B2) at (22,-8) {};
                \node [draw=none] (C2) at (5,-25) {};
                \foreach \s/\col in {1.5/ProcessBlue!20!white, 1/SkyBlue!20!white, 0/ProcessBlue!20!white}{
                \path [draw,\col, line width=40] ($(A2.west)-(0,\s cm)$) to ($(C2.west)-(0,\s cm)$) to ($(B2.west)-(0,\s cm)$);
         } 
        %        
        \node [draw=none,text width=\textwidth/1.7] (T1) at (10,0) {\fontsize{50}{50}\MakeUppercase{\textsf{\textbf{A Book Title}}}};
        %
        \node [draw=none,text width=\textwidth/1.7] (T2) at (10,-14) {
        \fontsize{20}{20}\textsf{\textbf{\textcolor{ProcessBlue}{Subtitle}}}\\
        \vspace*{0.02\textheight}
        \LARGE{\lipsum[1]}        
        };
        %
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I got `Latexmk: Failure in processing file './test.tex':
   'pdflatex' needed too many passes` while compiling your first example

Answer (score 18):

From my master's thesis. In the background one can see some (dirty) nanoparticles

[image]

Code:

```
\titlehead{%
\tikzexternaldisable
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[inner sep=0,opacity=1] at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{bgtitle.jpg}};
\begin{scope}
        %\path[clip,decoration={random steps, segment length=6pt, amplitude=2pt},
            %decorate] ($(current page.south west)+(5.1,6)$) -- ++(9,0) -- ++ (0,2) -- ++ (-1.5,4) -- ++ (0.5,2) -- ++ (-0.35,2) -- ++ (1,1) -- ++ (3.5,0.5) -- ++ (0,5) -- ++ (-4.75,0) -- ++ (-0.5,0.75) -- ++ (-4.25,0) -- ++ (-0.25,0.25) -- ++ (0,2) -- ++(-5.25,0) -- ++ (0,-8.25) -- ++ (0.25,-0.25) -- ++ (4,0) -- ++ (0.5,-0.75) -- ++ (-0.35,-2) -- ++ (0.5,-2) -- ++ (-2,-4) -- cycle;
            \path[clip,decoration={random steps, segment length=6pt, amplitude=2pt},
            decorate] ($(current page.south west)+(5.1,5)$) -- ++(12.15,0) -- ++ (0,12.5) -- ++ (0,5) -- ++ (-4.75,0) -- ++ (-0.5,0.75) -- ++ (-4.25,0) -- ++ (-0.25,0.25) -- ++ (0,2) -- ++(-5.25,0) -- ++ (0,-8.25) -- ++ (0,-12.15) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=white,inner sep=0,opacity=0.5] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\tikzexternalenable
\addfontfeatures{Numbers=Lining}%
  {University of YourTown\\
   Physics Department\\
   Physics Institute
   }}
\subject{\textit{\textbf{aster's esis}}\vspace*{-1cm}}
\publishers{\vspace{0.7cm}\addfontfeatures{Numbers=Lining}\large \begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
                         \indent\newlength{\titlepagenewlengthup}\setlength{\titlepagenewlengthup}{\widthof{1 }}\hphantom{2ⁿ }\hspace*{-\titlepagenewlengthup}1 supervisor: Professor Doctor Doe\\
                        2ⁿ supervisor: Professor Doctor Doe\\
                         \newlength{\titlepagenewlength}\setlength{\titlepagenewlength}{\widthof{ad}}\hphantom{2ⁿ super}\hspace*{-\titlepagenewlength}advisor: Doctor Doe\end{minipage}\vspace*{-0.7cm}}
\author{Max Mustermann}
\title{%
    \vspace{0.3cm}%
    \hrule height 2pt%
    \vspace{0.3cm} Title of thesis%
    \vspace{0.3cm}%
    \hrule height 2pt%
    \vspace{0.3cm}}
\subtitle{\vspace*{1.0cm}\includegraphics{Logo1}}
\date{\today}
```

Comment: I like it. Plus thank you for uploading the code next to it.

Answer (score 13):

I have few examples to show. You can download these from [Here](http://www.parsilatex.com/joomla/attachments/article/188/book-titlepage-examples1.zip), [Here](http://www.parsilatex.com/joomla/attachments/article/190/book-titlepage-examples2.zip), [Here](http://www.parsilatex.com/joomla/attachments/article/191/titlepage-examples3.zip), and [Here](http://www.parsilatex.com/joomla/attachments/article/192/titlepage-examples4.zip). These are originally Peter Wilson's titlepage examples that I have changed the examples little to work with [xepersian](http://ctan.org/pkg/xepersian) package to typeset Persian documents.

Several examples from the 4th archive:

1

[image: 4/1]

3

[image: 4/3]

5

[image: 4/5]

Answer (score 12):

For my school (something decent):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,fouriernc}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\definecolor{lime}{RGB}{0,0,128}
\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
            \fill[lime!10] (current page.south east) rectangle (current page.north west);
            \fill[lime,even odd rule] (current page.south west) rectangle ([xshift=1.5cm]current page.north west) ($(current page.north west)!.5!(current page.south west)$) arc(180:270:3) ($(current page.north west)!.5!(current page.south west)$) arc(270:450:3.5) ([yshift=7cm]$(current page.north west)!.5!(current page.south west)$)  arc(180:90:3);
%           \draw[lime!10,double=lime!10,double distance=2mm] (current page.south west) --+ (2,2) --+ (-2,6) --+ (2,8) --+ (-2,9) --+ (2,13) --+ (-2,18) --+ (2,30);
                \draw[lime,thin] (13,-1) node[lime,above left] {\Huge\it Teacher} --+ (0,3) node[lime,below right] {\Huge Q11};
            \node[yshift=-5cm,xslant=1,yscale=1.6,lime!40,opacity=.2] at (9.5,-6.5) {\scalebox{6}{Mathematik}};
            \node[yshift=-5cm,lime] at (8,-7) {\scalebox{6}{Mathematik}};
                \draw[lime,fill=lime!20] ([xshift=-1cm]current page.north east) -- ([yshift=-1cm]current page.north east) -- ([yshift=-2cm]current page.north east) -- ([xshift=-2cm]current page.north east);
            \path ([xshift=-1cm]current page.north east) -- ([yshift=-1cm]current page.north east) node[midway,sloped,below=.1cm,lime] {My Name};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 12):

Hope it's OK to share my own example – the title page I created, inspired by this very thread, for [notes I took in an algebraic geometry class](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/a.debray/lecture_notes/m390c_AGnotes.pdf) a few years back.

[image]

TeX source:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\begin{document}

\DeclareFixedFont{\titlefont}{T1}{ppl}{b}{}{0.7in}
\DeclareFixedFont{\subtitlefont}{T1}{ppl}{b}{}{0.4in}
\afterpage{\restoregeometry}
\newgeometry{left=1in, right=1in,top=1in, bottom=0in}
\definecolor{mytan}{HTML}{F6D5A8}
\pagecolor{mytan}\afterpage{\nopagecolor}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{flushright}
\titlefont Algebraic Geometry\\
\subtitlefont UT Austin, Spring 2016
\end{flushright}
\vfill
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[scope fading=north, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]{
 \makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{../the-great-wave-off-kanagawa}}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

% for additional pages after the title, uncomment the following line first:
% \clearpage

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11):

I used Harish Kumar and azetina code and add this falling dominos picture from
tikz example (http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/dominoes/):

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%                               PREAMBLE
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{epigraph}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%                            Cover Page Details
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{3D/.cd,
  x/.store in=\xx, x=0,
  y/.store in=\yy, y=0,
  z/.store in=\zz, z=0
}

\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{3D}{%
  \tikzset{3D/.cd,#1}%
  \pgfpoint{sin(\yy)*(\xx)}{-((\xx)/75)^2+(\zz)/100*(\xx)}%
}
\renewcommand\epigraphflush{flushright}
\renewcommand\epigraphsize{\normalsize}
\setlength\epigraphwidth{0.7\textwidth}
\definecolor{titlepagecolor}{cmyk}{1,.60,0,.40}
\DeclareFixedFont{\titlefont}{T1}{ppl}{b}{it}{0.5in}
\makeatletter                       
\def\printauthor{%                  
    {\large \@author}}              
\makeatother
\author{%
    Author Names \\  %%%% Your Name
    Department \\    %%%% Department Name
    \texttt{Email Address}\vspace{5pt} \\ %%% Your Email Address
    }
\newcommand\titlepagedecoration{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round, very thin]
  \def\e{1260}
  \foreach \x [evaluate={\i=mod(\x+90,360); \j=int((\i<180)*2-1); \t=3;
    \sc=\x/\e; \n=int((\e-\x)/15+5); \X=\x/\e;}] in {10,25,...,\e} {

    \path [shift={(3D cs:x=\x-\t,y={3*sin(\x-\t)})}, yslant=cos(\x)/5]
      (-\X/2, 0)   coordinate (A')  ( \X/2, 0)   coordinate (B')
      ( \X/2,2*\X) coordinate (C')  (-\X/2,2*\X) coordinate (D');

    \path [shift={(3D cs:x=\x,y=3*sin \x)}, yslant=cos(\x)/5]
      (-\X/2, 0)   coordinate (A) ( \X/2, 0)   coordinate (B)
      ( \X/2,2*\X) coordinate (C) (-\X/2,2*\X) coordinate (D);

    \filldraw [black!90] (B) -- (B') -- (C') -- (C)  -- cycle;
    \filldraw [black!80] (A) -- (A') -- (D') -- (D)  -- cycle;
    \filldraw [black!70] (C) -- (D)  -- (D') -- (C') -- cycle;
    \filldraw [black]    (A) -- (B)  -- (C)  -- (D)  -- cycle;

    \node [text=white, shift={($(C)!0.5!(D)$)}, anchor=north,
      yslant=cos(\x)/5, font=\sf, scale=\sc*1.5] at (0,-.33*\X) {\n};
  }
  %
  \foreach \i [evaluate={\x=\i*30-10; \X=1; \n=int(5-\i); \xsl=\x/180}]
    in {1,...,4} {

    \path [shift={(3D cs:x=\x+\e,y=-3*\x/90)}, yslant=cos \e/5, xslant=\xsl]
      (-\X/2, 0)           coordinate (A) ( \X/2, 0)           coordinate (B)
      ( \X/2, \X*2-\x/360) coordinate (C) (-\X/2, \X*2-\x/360) coordinate (D);

    \path [shift={(3D cs:x=\x+\e,y=-3*\x/90)}, shift={(5/50,5/50-\i*2/50)},
      yslant=cos \e/5, xslant=\xsl]
      (-\X/2, 0)           coordinate (A') ( \X/2, 0)           coordinate (B')
      ( \X/2, \X*2-\x/330) coordinate (C') (-\X/2, \X*2-\x/330) coordinate (D');

    \filldraw [black!70] (C) -- (D)  -- (D') -- (C') -- cycle;
    \filldraw [black!70] (A) -- (B)  -- (B') -- (A') -- cycle;
    \filldraw [black!90] (B) -- (B') -- (C') -- (C)  -- cycle;
    \filldraw [black]    (A) -- (B)  -- (C)  -- (D)  -- cycle;

    \node [text=white, shift={($(C)!0.5!(D)$)}, anchor=north, xslant=\xsl,
      yslant=cos \e/5, font=\sf, scale=1.5] at (0,-.33*\X) {\n};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%                               COVER
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\noindent
\titlefont Chapter 1\par
\epigraph{Pure mathematics is on the whole distinctly more useful than applied. For what is useful above all is technique, and mathematical technique is taught mainly through pure mathematics.}%
{\textit{London 1941}\\ \textsc{G. H. Hardy}}
\null\vfill
\vspace*{1cm}
\noindent
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.35\linewidth}
    \begin{flushright}
        \printauthor
    \end{flushright}
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}{0.02\linewidth}
    \rule{1pt}{60pt}
\end{minipage}
\titlepagedecoration
\end{titlepage}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%                            START HERE
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Test}
This is a test. 
\[
\pi \approx 3.14159 26535 89793 23846  \]
    \[
        e=2+\cfrac{1}
          {1+\cfrac{1}
          {2+\cfrac{1}
          {1+\cfrac{1}
          {1+\cfrac{1}
          {4+\cfrac{1}
          {1+\cfrac{1}
          {1+\cfrac{1}
          {6+\cdots}}}}}}}}
    \]
\end{document}
```

which will produce this
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Not a really funcy one but it is nice. I used [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/245904/248968) post. Of course all the colours, the language and the font size can change.

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{parcolumns}
\usepackage[english, greek]{babel}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pagecolor}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec,}
\usepackage[series={},nocritical,noend,noeledsec,nofamiliar,noledgroup]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}


\titleformat{\chapter}
{\flushright\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\color{burntorange}}{\thechapter}{1em}{}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{-18pt}{-102pt}{10pt}

\titleformat{\section}
{\center\normalfont\large\bfseries\color{amaranth} }{\thesection}{1em}{}

\title{\textit{ \textbf{\textcolor{azure}{\textlatin{TITLE}}}}}
\author{\Large{\bfseries {\textcolor{burntorange}{\textlatin{AUTHOR}}}
        
        \definecolor{burlywood}{rgb}{0.87, 0.72, 0.53}
        
        \usepackage[%
        margin=4cm
        %,showframe% to show the page layout
        ]{geometry}
        \usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament}
        
        \newcommand\om{5mm}% ornament margin
        \newcommand\ow{5cm}% ornament width
        \newcommand\ols{5.5mm}% ornament line shift
        \newcommand\on{63}% ornament number
        \colorlet{bordercolor}{burlywood}
        \tikzset{
            ol/.style={line width=1mm,dotted}% style for the lines
        }
        
        % define the border and save it in a box
        \newsavebox\border
        \sbox\border{%
            \tikz[color=bordercolor]{
                \useasboundingbox(0,0)rectangle(\paperwidth,-\paperheight);
                \foreach[count=\i]\a/\p/\s in {%
                    north west/{\om,-\om}/none,
                    north east/{{\paperwidth-\om},-\om}/v,
                    south east/{{\paperwidth-\om},{-\paperheight+\om}}/c,%
                    south west/{\om,{-\paperheight+\om}}/h%
                }\node[anchor=\a](n\i) at (\p){\pgfornament[width=\ow,symmetry=\s]{\on}};
                \begin{scope}[ol]
                    \draw([yshift=-\ols]n1.north east)--([yshift=-\ols]n2.north west);
                    \draw([xshift=-\ols]n2.south east)--([xshift=-\ols]n3.north east);
                    \draw([yshift=\ols]n3.south west)--([yshift=\ols]n4.south east);
                    \draw([xshift=\ols]n4.north west)--([xshift=\ols]n1.south west);
                \end{scope}
            }%
        }
        
        \usepackage[manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
        \clearpairofpagestyles
        \cfoot*{\pagemark}
        
        % define a switch to enable and disable the border
        \newif\ifBorder
        % define a new layer
        \DeclareNewLayer[{%
            background,
            page,
            contents={\ifBorder\usebox\border\fi}
        }]{border.bg}
        % add the border layer to all layer page styles (scrheadings, plain, empty, ...) ...
        \AddLayersAtBeginOfPageStyle{@everystyle@}{border.bg}
        
        
        
        
        \usepackage{graphics}
        \definecolor{burntorange}{rgb}{0.8, 0.33, 0.0}
        \definecolor{azure}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 1.0}
        \definecolor{amaranth}{rgb}{0.9, 0.17, 0.31}
        \definecolor{dg}{rgb}{0.0, 0.0, 1.0}
        \definecolor{dr}{rgb}{1.0, 0.13, 0.32}
        \definecolor{cerulean}{rgb}{0.0, 0.48, 0.65}
        \definecolor{bv}{rgb}{0.8,0.0,0.0}
        \definecolor{buff}{rgb}{0.94, 0.86, 0.51}
        
        \usepackage[colorlinks, unicode]{hyperref}
        \begin{document}
            
            \begin{titlepage}
                \pagecolor{buff}
                \Bordertrue% enable the border
                {\raggedright
                    
                    \begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}\raggedright    
                        {\itshape\bfseries\color{burntorange}       \textlatin{INSTITUTION} }
                \end{minipage}}
                \begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}\raggedleft
                    {\itshape\bfseries\color{burntorange} \textlatin{SCHOOL}
                }\end{minipage}
                \centering
                %
                
                
                \Large
                \vspace{3cm}
                
                \vspace{2cm}
                
                \rule{\textwidth}{1.6pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace*{2pt}
                \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\\[\baselineskip]
                \vspace{14pt}
                
                {\bfseries
                    \Huge\color{azure}  \itshape
                    \textlatin{TITLE}%
                }
                \\
                
                
                \par
                \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace{3.2pt}
                \rule{\textwidth}{1.6pt}\\[\baselineskip]
                \vspace{2cm}
                %ΗΜΕΡΟΜΗΝΙΑ
                {\normalsize \today}
                
            \end{titlepage}
        

        \clearpage
                \Borderfalse% disable the border
                \pagecolor{white}
    
     \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Plus I think [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41159/does-anybody-know-a-good-source-of-free-ornaments-decorations-frames-backgr) answer deserves an applause:

Answer (score 3):

My cover book (picture and code changed for a typo - thanks CarLaTex!) :
[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{ shapes.geometric }
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\setlength{\parskip}{4cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{-1.5cm}
\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Background %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \fill[blue!50] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
        
        
        \foreach \i in {2,...,22}
        {
            \node[rounded corners,blue!2,draw,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=5, minimum size=\i cm,ultra thick] at ($(current page.south)+(0,1)$) {} ;
        }
        
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Background Polygon %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
        \foreach \i in {0,...,15}
        {
            \node[rounded corners,blue!2,draw,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=12, minimum size=\i cm,ultra thick] at ($(current page.west)+(1.5,0)$) {} ;
        }
        \foreach \i in {0,...,15}
    {
        \node[rounded corners,blue!2,draw,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=12, minimum size=\i cm,ultra thick] at ($(current page.east)+(-1.5,0)$) {} ;
    }   
%       \foreach \i in {2,...,22}
%       {
%           \node[rounded corners,blue!2,draw,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=18, minimum size=\i cm,ultra thick] at ($(current page.north)+(0,-4.5)$) {} ;
%       }
        
        
%       \foreach \i in {21,...,6}
%       {
%           \node[cyan!20,rounded corners,draw,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=12, minimum size=\i cm,ultra thick] at ($(current page.south east)+(-0.5,0.45)$) {} ;
%       }
        
        
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Title of the Report %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
        \node[left,white,minimum width=0.625*\paperwidth,minimum height=3cm, rounded corners] at ($(current page.north)+(6.7,-5)$)
        {
            {\fontsize{40}{45} \selectfont \bfseries TRIGONOMETRIA}
        };
        
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Subtitle %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
        \node[left,white,minimum width=0.625*\paperwidth,minimum height=2cm, rounded corners] at ($(current page.north)+(7,-6.2)$)
        {
            {\LARGE \textbf{Per neo docenti di matematica, studenti,  cultori}}
        };
        
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Author Name %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
        \node[left,white,minimum width=0.625*\paperwidth,minimum height=2cm, rounded corners] at ($(current page.north)+(6.7,-3)$)
        {
            {\huge \textbf{Raffaele Santoro}}
        };
    
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Year %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
        \node[rounded corners,fill=blue!10,text =blue,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=5, minimum size=3.5 cm,inner sep=0,ultra thick] at ($(current page.south)+(0,1)$) {
            \includegraphics[scale=.8]{RSEdizioni.png}
        };
        
    \end{tikzpicture}\\

\includegraphics[scale=1]{fg_b.png}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: "studemti"? Are you sure?

Comment: @CarLaTeX NO!!! It's one 'errore di sbaglio'...

Comment: Ahahah, ciao compaesano!

Answer (score 3):

I hope you find this at least interesting. The background image is from a website for free images:

Book cover: [image]

It's for my in-progress book. Code:

```
% !TeX spellcheck = es_ES
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book} 
\usepackage{titletoc}       
\usepackage{ucs}                
\usepackage[spanish,es-nodecimaldot]{babel} 
\usepackage{fontspec}       
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}       
\setsansfont{URWClassico}[
    Path=./URWClassico/,
    Extension = .otf,
    UprightFont=*-Regular,
    BoldFont=*-Bold,
    ItalicFont=*-Italic,
    BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic
    ]   
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
    \definecolor{orangy}{RGB}{255,122,4}
    \definecolor{blueish}{RGB}{4,122,255}
    \definecolor{aqua}{RGB}{0,100,150}
    \definecolor{deepblue}{RGB}{0,102,205}
    \definecolor{yellowish}{RGB}{255,255,0}
    \definecolor{chapopcolor}{RGB}{0,100,150}
\usepackage{wallpaper} 
\usepackage[skip=0.4em,indent=1em]{parskip}
    \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1}   
    \raggedbottom       
\usepackage{graphicx}
    \graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{tikz}    
    \usetikzlibrary{babel}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc,positioning,shapes,arrows,decorations.pathmorphing}
    \usetikzlibrary{cd}
\usepackage[left=4cm,right=4cm,top=2.7cm,bottom=2.5cm,outer=3cm,inner=3cm,heightrounded]{geometry}  
\usepackage[breaklinks=true,
colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue!22!black,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=black,anchorcolor=blue!70!black,
bookmarks=true,pdfpagelayout=TwoPageRight]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}       
\usepackage{varwidth}        
    \tcbuselibrary{breakable,skins,theorems}



\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\begin{titlepage}
\newgeometry{left=7.5cm,top=1.2cm,right=1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node[opacity=1,inner sep=0pt] at (current page.center)
{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{wall/wall45b}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\vphantom{A}
\vfill
\noindent{\fontsize{70}{48} \selectfont \bfseries\sffamily lógica básica.}
\\{\fontsize{20}{48} \selectfont \bfseries\sffamily una introducción al arte del razonamiento}
\par
\noindent
\makebox[0pt][l]{\rule{1.3\textwidth}{1pt}}
\par
\noindent
{\large\sffamily \href{mailto:}{\bfseries carlos romero}}
\par
\vskip\baselineskip
\noindent \textsf{(versión parcial de \today.)}
\end{titlepage}
\restoregeometry
\pagecolor{white}
\pagestyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I can post also code if requested.

Comment: It would be interesting.