# Trying to do graphical decorations in "ClassicThesis style"

Tags: classicthesis, decorations

Is there a way to obtain an effect like the page below? The gray tones of the effect in the page below are uniforms but I would have different tones among the various shapes. The main gray tone should be the following:

```
\definecolor{halfgray}{gray}{0.55}
\color{halfgray}% in classicthesis
```

I think that, this decoration should be applied (if this experiment is successful) only at the first page of each chapter...

[image]

```
\documentclass[headinclude,footinclude]{scrbook}

\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers,pdfspacing]{classicthesis}

\usepackage{arsclassica}

\begin{document}
\chapter{graphic test}
\section{graphic test}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin et metus vel diam tempus egestas in ut sem. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vivamus justo orci, porttitor at tempor ut, gravida at urna. Donec facilisis purus quis dolor viverra non cursus turpis fermentum. Phasellus elit metus, interdum vitae semper id, consequat at sem. Quisque sollicitudin purus enim. Fusce ultrices libero at neque dignissim eleifend. Vestibulum est libero, accumsan vitae ullamcorper sit amet, laoreet vel mauris. Quisque id odio sapien, non ultrices justo. Nulla sit amet magna nunc, in tempor lectus. Maecenas vitae sem nec mi tincidunt vehicula.
\end{document}
```

---

To be clear, I wouldn't this behaviour, but I would that the decoration go always in the bigger margin... (I've have used `openany`)

[image]

Comment: Me too!  Notice that you'll probably want to print on a larger paper and crop it, since printers usually cannot print too close to the paper border.

Comment: I like the idea, but just from a design perspective I find it is a bit too much for a page that also has a lot of text on it. I think it would look nice on the title page or the "parts" page. But of course this is subjective and just a comment :-)

Comment: @Jörg But it would be a shame because the most of times aren't used the parts : S However Thanks for the advice/comment ! : )

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Here's one possibility using TikZ; `\chapterdecoration` is automatically invoked  using the last optional argument of `\titleformat` for `\chapter` as given in `arsclassica.sty`:

```
\documentclass[headinclude,footinclude]{scrbook}
\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers,pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{arsclassica}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]%
        {\normalfont\Large\sffamily}%
        {{\color{halfgray}\chapterNumber\thechapter%
        \hspace{10pt}\vline}  }{10pt}%
        {\spacedallcaps}[\chapterdecoration]

\definecolor{halfgray}{gray}{0.55}

\newcommand\chapterdecoration{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,shorten >= -10pt]

\coordinate (aux1) at ([yshift=-15pt]current page.north east);
\coordinate (aux2) at ([yshift=-410pt]current page.north east);
\coordinate (aux3) at ([xshift=-4.5cm]current page.north east);
\coordinate (aux4) at ([yshift=-150pt]current page.north east);

\begin{scope}[halfgray!40,line width=12pt,rounded corners=12pt]
\draw
  (aux1) -- coordinate (a)
  ++(225:5) --
  ++(-45:5.1) coordinate (b);
\draw[shorten <= -10pt]
  (aux3) --
  (a) --
  (aux1);
\draw[opacity=0.6,halfgray,shorten <= -10pt]
  (b) --
  ++(225:2.2) --
  ++(-45:2.2);
\end{scope}
\draw[halfgray,line width=8pt,rounded corners=8pt,shorten <= -10pt]
  (aux4) --
  ++(225:0.8) --
  ++(-45:0.8);
\begin{scope}[halfgray!70,line width=6pt,rounded corners=8pt]
\draw[shorten <= -10pt]
  (aux2) --
  ++(225:3) coordinate[pos=0.45] (c) --
  ++(-45:3.1);
\draw
  (aux2) --
  (c) --
  ++(135:2.5) --
  ++(45:2.5) --
  ++(-45:2.5) coordinate[pos=0.3] (d);   
\draw 
  (d) -- +(45:1);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{graphic test}
\section{graphic test}
\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

In a comment, **FormlessCloud** asked for a change so that the decoration will always appear in the outer margin (this, of course, if the `openany` class option is active); here's the necessary modification:

```
\documentclass[headinclude,footinclude,openany]{scrbook}
\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers,pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{arsclassica}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\strictpagecheck

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]%
        {\normalfont\Large\sffamily}%
        {{\color{halfgray}\chapterNumber\thechapter%
        \hspace{10pt}\vline}  }{10pt}%
        {\spacedallcaps}[\chapterdecoration]

\definecolor{halfgray}{gray}{0.55}

\newcommand\anglei{-45}
\newcommand\angleii{45}
\newcommand\angleiii{225}
\newcommand\angleiv{135}

\newcommand\chapterdecoration{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,shorten >= -10pt]
\coordinate (aux1) at ([yshift=-15pt]current page.north east);
\coordinate (aux2) at ([yshift=-410pt]current page.north east);
\coordinate (aux3) at ([xshift=-4.5cm]current page.north east);
\coordinate (aux4) at ([yshift=-150pt]current page.north east);
\checkoddpage
\ifoddpage
\else
\coordinate (aux1) at ([yshift=-15pt]current page.north west);
\coordinate (aux2) at ([yshift=-410pt]current page.north west);
\coordinate (aux3) at ([xshift=4.5cm]current page.north west);
\coordinate (aux4) at ([yshift=-150pt]current page.north west);
\renewcommand\anglei{-135}
\renewcommand\angleii{135}
\renewcommand\angleiii{-45}
\renewcommand\angleiv{45}
\fi
\begin{scope}[halfgray!40,line width=12pt,rounded corners=12pt]
\draw
  (aux1) -- coordinate (a)
  ++(\angleiii:5) --
  ++(\anglei:5.1) coordinate (b);
\draw[shorten <= -10pt]
  (aux3) --
  (a) --
  (aux1);
\draw[opacity=0.6,halfgray,shorten <= -10pt]
  (b) --
  ++(\angleiii:2.2) --
  ++(\anglei:2.2);
\end{scope}
\draw[halfgray,line width=8pt,rounded corners=8pt,shorten <= -10pt]
  (aux4) --
  ++(\angleiii:0.8) --
  ++(\anglei:0.8);
\begin{scope}[halfgray!70,line width=6pt,rounded corners=8pt]
\draw[shorten <= -10pt]
  (aux2) --
  ++(\angleiii:3) coordinate[pos=0.45] (c) --
  ++(\anglei:3.1);
\draw
  (aux2) --
  (c) --
  ++(\angleiv:2.5) --
  ++(\angleii:2.5) --
  ++(\anglei:2.5) coordinate[pos=0.3] (d);   
\draw 
  (d) -- +(\angleii:1);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\mbox{}\newpage%just for the example
\chapter{graphic test}
\section{graphic test}
\lipsum[1-3]
\chapter{graphic test}
\section{graphic test}
\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

An image of the two pages containing the beginning of a chapter, illustrating the alternancy in the margin:

[image]

Comment: Very good! I have only changed: `xshift=2pt` to `xshift=3pt` of darkest shape and the color of `\vline` in the `tileformat` command, you have changed it in `halfgray`...

Comment: @FormlessCloud I introduced some improvements to the code using auxiliary coordinates.

Comment: This code works only for the right pages, right?

Comment: @FormlessCloud yes; do you need a version that also works for left (even-numbered) pages?

Comment: @FormlessCloud I've done some tests and, using the `twoside`, `openany` class options, the code will produce the decoration in the outer margin for odd-numbered pages and in the inner margin for even-numbered pages. Is this the expected behaviour or do you want anything else?

Comment: Try to check my updated question...

Comment: I would that the code produce the decoration only in the outer margin in even and odd-numbered pages both,because the effect of the decoration in the inner margin is very ugly for me

Comment: @FormlessCloud ah, I see. Please see my updated answer.