# Customizing title page in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, rotating

I put the following tikzpicture, borrowed from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86310/10898, in my beamer title page.

Nevertheless, I would like to try two things. On one hand, put the tikzfigure in an horizontal way with respect to the page, and if posible, in the second case reduce the width of the title colorbox.

Any hints in order to proceed???. Your help will be highly appreciated!

```
\documentclass[8pt,onlymath,usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}                         
\definecolor{titlecolor}{RGB}{0,173,239}

  \mode<presentation>{
    \usetheme{Warsaw}
    \usefonttheme{structurebold}
    \setbeamerfont{title}{family={\fontfamily{ppl}},series=\bfseries,size=\LARGE,shape=\itshape}

    \definecolor{steelblue3}{rgb}{0.31,0.58,0.8}
    \colorlet{structure}{steelblue3}
    \usecolortheme[named=steelblue3]{structure}

    \setbeamercovered{transparent}

    \definecolor{skyblue3}{rgb}{0.42,0.65,0.8} 
    \setbeamercolor{blocks}{fg=black,bg=skyblue3}

    \definecolor{purple4}{rgb}{0.33,0.1,0.55}
    \setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=purple4}

    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

    \let\Tiny=\tiny
    \setbeamersize{text margin left=0.4cm,text margin right=0.4cm}
    }

\newcommand\titlepagedecoration{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5,remember picture,overlay,shorten >= -10pt]

\coordinate (aux1) at ([yshift=-15pt] current page.north east); %1st two triangles
\coordinate (aux2) at ([yshift=-410pt]current page.north east); %last two triangles
\coordinate (aux3) at ([xshift=-4.5cm]current page.north east); %1st two triangles
\coordinate (aux4) at ([yshift=-150pt]current page.north east);

\begin{scope}[titlecolor!40,line width=6pt,rounded corners=6pt]
\draw
  (aux1) -- coordinate (a)
  ++(225:5) --
  ++(-45:5.1) coordinate (b);
\draw[shorten <= -10pt]
  (aux3) --
  (a) --
  (aux1);
\draw[opacity=0.6,titlecolor,shorten <= -10pt]
  (b) --
  ++(225:2.2) --
  ++(-45:2.2);
\end{scope}
\draw[titlecolor,line width=4pt,rounded corners=4pt,shorten <= -10pt]
  (aux4) --
  ++(225:0.8) --
  ++(-45:0.8);
\begin{scope}[titlecolor!70,line width=2pt,rounded corners=4pt]
\draw[shorten <= -10pt]
  (aux2) --
  ++(225:3) coordinate[pos=0.45] (c) --
  ++(-45:3.1);
\draw
  (aux2) --
  (c) --
  ++(135:2.5) --
  ++(45:2.5) --
  ++(-45:2.5) coordinate[pos=0.3] (d);   
\draw 
  (d) -- +(45:1);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\vspace*{2.5pt}
\title[Conference-Year]{Title of the presentation}
\vspace*{.8cm}\author[Author]{\textcolor{steelblue3}{\textbf{{\Large Author}}} \\ \vspace{.5cm} }
\date{\textcolor{steelblue3}{\small\bf  Conference\\Place, Month Year}}

\begin{document}

\titlepagedecoration
\begin{frame}[plain]
\vspace*{-1cm}
   \begin{columns}
   \begin{column}{1.9cm}
      \centering
    Logo1
   \end{column}


   \begin{column}{7cm}
    \centering
    {\textbf{\textcolor{steelblue3}{Center \\ Institute \\ Department}}}
   \end{column}

   \begin{column}{2cm}
   \centering
    Logo2
   \end{column}
  \end{columns}

  \vspace{1cm}
 \titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

UPDATED:

I tried with the rotating package for my first question but i didn't succeed. While for my second question, i used this code 
`\setbeamertemplate{title page}[default][rounded=true,shadow=true,wd=0.8\textwidth]` and now the colorbox is shorter, however it is not centered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one possibility; adjust the settings according to your needs:

```
\documentclass[8pt,onlymath,usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}                         
\definecolor{titlecolor}{RGB}{0,173,239}

  \mode<presentation>{
    \usetheme{Warsaw}
    \usefonttheme{structurebold}
    \setbeamerfont{title}{family={\fontfamily{ppl}},series=\bfseries,size=\LARGE,shape=\itshape}

    \definecolor{steelblue3}{rgb}{0.31,0.58,0.8}
    \colorlet{structure}{steelblue3}
    \usecolortheme[named=steelblue3]{structure}

    \setbeamercovered{transparent}

    \definecolor{skyblue3}{rgb}{0.42,0.65,0.8} 
    \setbeamercolor{blocks}{fg=black,bg=skyblue3}

    \definecolor{purple4}{rgb}{0.33,0.1,0.55}
    \setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=purple4}

    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

    \let\Tiny=\tiny
    \setbeamersize{text margin left=0.4cm,text margin right=0.4cm}
    }

\newcommand\titlepagedecoration{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5,remember picture,overlay,shorten >= -10pt]

\coordinate (aux1) at ([xshift=15pt] current page.north west); %1st two triangles
\coordinate (aux2) at ([xshift=410pt]current page.north west); %last two triangles
\coordinate (aux3) at ([yshift=-4cm]current page.north west); %1st two triangles
\coordinate (aux4) at ([xshift=150pt]current page.north west);

\begin{scope}[titlecolor!40,line width=6pt,rounded corners=6pt]
\draw
  (aux1) -- coordinate (a)
  ++(-45:5) --
  ++(45:5.1) coordinate (b);
\draw[shorten <= -10pt]
  (aux3) --
  (a) --
  (aux1);
\draw[opacity=0.6,titlecolor,shorten <= -10pt]
  (b) --
  ++(-45:2.2) --
  ++(45:2.2);
\end{scope}
\draw[titlecolor,line width=4pt,rounded corners=4pt,shorten <= -10pt]
  (aux4) --
  ++(-45:0.8) --
  ++(45:0.8);
\begin{scope}[titlecolor!70,line width=2pt,rounded corners=4pt]
\draw[shorten <= -10pt]
  (aux2) --
  ++(-45:3) coordinate[pos=0.45] (c) --
  ++(45:3.1);
\draw
  (aux2) --
  (c) --
  ++(225:2.5) --
  ++(135:2.5) --
  ++(45:2.5) coordinate[pos=0.3] (d);   
\draw 
  (d) -- +(135:1);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\title[Conference-Year]{Title of the presentation}
\vspace*{.8cm}\author[Author]{\textcolor{steelblue3}{\textbf{{\Large Author}}} \\ \vspace{.5cm} }
\date{\textcolor{steelblue3}{\small\bf  Conference\\Place, Month Year}}

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{mydefault}[1][]
{
  \vbox{}
  \vfill
  \begingroup
    \centering
    \parbox{.75\paperwidth}{% change the width here
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\linewidth,sep=8pt,center,#1]{title}
      \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
      \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
        \vskip0.25em%
        {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
      \fi%     
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    }
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{author}
      \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{institute}
      \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{date}
      \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
    \end{beamercolorbox}\vskip0.5em
    {\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic\par}
  \endgroup
  \vfill
}
\setbeamertemplate{title page}[mydefault][colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=\beamer@themerounded@shadow]
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\titlepagedecoration
\begin{frame}[plain]
\vspace*{-1cm}
   \begin{columns}
   \begin{column}{1.9cm}
      \centering
    Logo1
   \end{column}


   \begin{column}{7cm}
    \centering
    {\textbf{\textcolor{steelblue3}{Center \\ Institute \\ Department}}}
   \end{column}

   \begin{column}{2cm}
   \centering
    Logo2
   \end{column}
  \end{columns}

  \vspace{1cm}
 \titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The width for the `beamercolorbox` used for the title is now controlled by the width of a `\parbox` and it is set initially to `0.75\paperwidth`; you can change this value in the line marked with `% change the width here`.

Comment: Thank you very much @Gonzalo Medina. Your suggestion was very helpfull.