# Insert Picture on Titlepage

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, memoir, diagrams, titles

I have made a titlepage with a wide (104pt) vertical line and i want to place a logo on top of that line. I tried to do it with icluding a picture with tikzpicture, but it places the image at the bottom of the page and I can't move it.

This is my code:

```
\newcommand*{\titleREP}{\begingroup{
\vspace{5cm}
\hspace{-2cm} % Whitespace to the left of the page
\color{darkgreen}\rule{104pt}{\textheight} % vertical line
\color{black}
\hspace*{0.1\textwidth}
\parbox[b]{0.9\textwidth{
{\noindent\Huge\bfseries MyTitleOfTheReport} \\[2\baselineskip]
{\Large \textit{The subtitle}} [4\baselineskip}
{\Large \textsc{The Author}}
\vspace{0.5\textheight}
{\noindent Organization}\\[\baselineskip]
}}
\endgroup

\begin{document}
\titleREP
\end{document}
```

The document is a memoir class document btw.

I tried inserting the picture everywhere with the following command:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\includegraphics[height = 2cm]{Logo}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but I can't change the position where it is placed. How can i do that?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about)

Comment: @Dewey, Your code doesn't compile; among other things, there are typos (\newcomand instead of `\newcommand`, \bfserues instead of `\bfseries`). For guidance in creating your titlepage, you should look up: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation#A_practical_example.

Comment: @Dewey Also, I don't think there is a need to put `\includegraphics` in a `tikzpicture` environment, here.

Comment: OK I removed the typo. I'm at work and can't install software on my pc so I'm writing with the report on my laptop with no internet connection. I'll try your suggestions!

Comment: You can put the `\includegraphics` without a `tikzpicture` environment. The only reason to use tikz here is if you want to put the figure _inside a tikz node_ and give the coordinates of this node for absolute positioning in the page (using `current page` anchors). In this case you should use `[remember picture, overlay]` options for the tikz picture, and compile twice.

Answer (score 1):

Your code do not compile for me, but if I understand you correctly you want something like
[image]
One approach (which uses `\includegraphics` and `tikz` as you suggested) could be

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlingpage}

\begin{minipage}{105pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill (0,0) -- (104pt,0) -- (104pt,-\textheight) -- (0,-\textheight) -- cycle;  % black strip
\node at (52pt,0) [below] { % logo
\tikz\fill[very thick,white] (0,0) circle (45pt); % not the logo (remove me)
% \includegraphics[height=2cm]{Logo}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.6\textwidth}
{\Huge\bfseries Title Of The Report}

{\Large\itshape The subtitle}

\vspace{1cm}

{\Large\scshape The Author}
\end{minipage}

\end{titlingpage}

\end{document}
```

I will also like to draw your attention to [Sam­ple ti­tlepages, and how to code them](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlepages) and [Showcase of beautiful title page done in TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85904/showcase-of-beautiful-title-page-done-in-tex); just for inspiration `:-)`