# pdfpages not working with classicthesis

Tags: pdftex, titles

I am trying to use a title page I found in this website ([Showcase of beautiful title page done in TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85904/showcase-of-beautiful-title-page-done-in-tex)) which begins with `\documentclass`. As I try to include it in the main tex file, LaTeX returns an error, because `\documentclass` is already used.

Then, I tried to execute the titlepage apart, obtaining a pdf which is the correct one, but only for what concerns the titlepage. To avoid such a stuff, I thought to include this pdf that I obtained by using the `pdfpages` packages. But LaTeX returns me an error:

> "Option clash for package xcolor."

If I ignore this, the compiler does not create the right table of content. The same mistake is done if I use TikZ packages. How can I solve it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: In the configuration file of classic thesis I simply add \usepackage{pdfpages} and this is the problem: LaTeX does not love it so much and it returns the error reported above. My aim would be to include a new title page which is not the original one provided by Classic Thesis. Another option would be modify the titlepage.tex already present but I do not know how to do it, beacause when I add TicZ LaTeX returns the same error. Here the code of my new title page:
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{epigraph}
...
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
...
and so on

Comment: Add your little snippet as a fully compilable example to your question by editing your question.

Comment: Without some more info this is unclear I'm afraid.