# Creating a Title Page for Maths dissertation

Tags: titles, covers

I'm a third year maths undergrad, and am currently writing my dissertation using TexMaker. I'm not that familiar with the program, and am struggling to create an appropriate cover page (including title/name/uni etc and abstract)

Is there a particular way I can achieve this? Everything just keeps grouping together and looks rather unsightly for a dissertation to be handed in!

Comment: Well, everything depends. Which documentclass are you using? You can typeset your own titlepage between `\begin{titlepage}` and `\end{titlepag}`

Comment: I would start with the formal layout requirements of your department. Also, ask around if previous cohorts of students have submitted their theses using LaTeX; if so, one or more of them may have created a template that you could re-use.

Comment: The document »[Some Examples of Title Pages](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlepages)« might give you some inspiration.

Comment: Amazing thank you! I seem to be getting the hang of it now, but how do I move my abstract so that it sits below my title but not too close and not too far? Like how do I create vertical space?

Comment: @SarahJayne: Please have a look on http://www.latextemplates.com/cat/title-pages  also.

Comment: @SarahJayne if you would like to add vertical space use `\vspace{<distance>}` to add some (`<distance>` can be in cm, in, pt, em, etc. It can also be negative.) Alternatively, after a line break (a double backslash `\\ `), you can add `[<distance>]`.

Comment: [Showcase of beautiful title page done in TeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/85904)

Answer (score 2):

Modify this to suit your needs and layout:

```
\documentclass{report}   %% assuming that your dissertation contains chapters.
\usepackage{kantlipsum,graphicx}
\begin{document}
  \begin{titlepage}
    \centering
    \vspace*{0.6in}
    \bgroup
    \Huge\bfseries This is the title of my dissertation in \verb|\Huge| font \par
    \egroup
    \vspace{0.5in}
    \bgroup
    \Large My name\\[0.1in]
    \egroup
    My department \par
    \vspace{0.5in}
    \bgroup
    Thesis submitted to the\\[0.2in]
    \Large My university 
    \egroup
    \par
    \vspace{0.5in}
    {\LARGE\bfseries Abstract}
    \par
    \vspace{0.1in}
    \hrule
    \vspace{0.1in}
    \begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}
     \kant[1]
    \end{minipage}
    \vspace{0.1in}
    \hrule
    \vspace{0.2in}
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}
    \vfill
    \today
  \end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image]