# Need help to create such a beautiful title page

Tags: titles

I have seen such a beautiful preamble (got the PDF from on of my studentfriends and need help to create such a beautiful titlepage. The black bands are to make the picture anonymous, to hide the identity of my friend.

But I just need such a beautiful titlepage for my instructors. No one of us has the preamble anymore :(

Kind regards

and thank you very much in advance.

Is it allowed to ask such a question in this forum?[image]

Comment: have a look at [Showcase of beautiful title page done in TeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/85904)

Comment: You can use `tabularx` package and `tabular` for the header and a `center` environment with small capitals `\textsc` or `\scshape` and font dimension switches (e.g., `\large`) for the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one uses `microtype` for the letter spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
\begingroup
    \noindent
    \bfseries
    \begin{tabular}{|p{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}p{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}|}
        \hline
        Received:            & Approved:  \cr
                             & Date:      \cr
                             & Signature: \cr
        (for the instructor) &            \cr
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\endgroup
\bigskip
\begingroup
    \centering
    \obeylines
    \scshape
    \lsstyle
    \large Modern Box
    \LARGE Aflering 3
    \Large John Boxer
    \large Institute for Boxes
    \large Box University
    \large 26/04/2014
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: but what should I do to get headers, footers and pagenumbering after this front page?

Comment: @user254805 Remove the `\pagestyle{empty}` and just put above your titlepage `\thispagestyle{empty}`. And please do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user254805".

Comment: Why did you use `\begingroup` `\endgroup` rather than `{` and `}`?  I notice that both work fine.

Comment: @AFeldman They are synonymous.  `\begingroup...\endgroup` feels more like a LaTeX environment and is easier to spot in the code whereas `{...}` is almost exclusively used to group arguments.

Comment: I thought the difference was that you can include control sequences in your `\endgroup` , or in `\begingroup` to allow grouping that would be otherwise not possible.  In the context of making a new group definition.  Am I wrong in that?

Comment: @AFeldman That is unfortuately wrong.  Their sole purpose is grouping.  But `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` can be unmatched within `{}`, so for example `{\begingroup...}\endgroup`.  For further detail read the [TeXbook](http://ctan.org/pkg/texbook).

Answer (score 2):

For the header you can use a `tabular` (or `tabularx`) environment. For the rest just a `center` environment with `\scshape` and a few font dimension switches.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|XX|}
\hline
\textbf{Received:} &  \textbf{Approved:}\\
                   &  \textbf{Date:}\\
                   &  \textbf{Signature:}\\
\textbf{(for the instructor)} & \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}


\begin{center}
\scshape Institute\\
\Large Course Name\\
\large Author\\

\medskip
\small \today
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]