# I do not know the keys /tcb/flush right upper -- pgfkeys error

Tags: pgfkeys, tcolorbox

On compiling with PdfLaTeX, the below MWE generates me the following error `I do not know the keys /tcb/flush right upper`. To resolve this issue, I downloaded `tcolorbox` and `pgfkeys` package from **CTAN** and placed them in my TeX installation folder (since TeXLive is frozen now) and ran `texhash` and updated the system. But yet I get the same here. Is there any other alternative to achieve the same?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\tcbset{
    pccstyle/.style={
        enhanced,flushright upper,
        boxrule=1.4pt,
        colback=white,colframe=black!50!yellow,
        drop fuzzy midday shadow=black!50!yellow
    }
}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\vspace*{1cm}
\mbox{}\hfill\scalebox{2}{
    \begin{tcolorbox}[pccstyle,width=6.8cm]
        {\bfseries\LARGE {Program Review} \par}
        {\large \itshape Mathematics \par}
        {\large Portland Community College }
    \end{tcolorbox}
}

\scalebox{2}{%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[pccstyle,width=4.8cm]
        {\scshape Fall 2008--Spring 2013}
    \end{tcolorbox}
}
\end{document}
```

The output of `\listfiles`:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
tcolorbox.sty    2013/05/15 version 2.22 text color boxes
     pgf.sty    2013/12/18 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.14)
  pgfrcs.sty    2013/12/20 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.28)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  pgfsys.sty    2013/11/30 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.47)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.1)
verbatim.sty    2003/08/22 v1.5q LaTeX2e package for verbatim enhancements
    tikz.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.142)
  pgffor.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.25)
 pgfkeys.sty
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
supp-pdf.mkii
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
 ***********
```

Comment: that code looks *mighty* familiar :) the `tcolorbox` almost certainly has a lot of dependencies - it's quite hard to predict what they all are, which is why it's best to use the official method: [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437)

Comment: I referred the code from here (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85904/showcase-of-beautiful-title-page-done-in-tex) @cmhughes :)

Comment: I used `tcolorbox` but you could probably get away with a fairly simple `tikz node` and the `shadow` library

Comment: I would be happy if you could help me with that @cmhughes :)

Comment: Best is to update your tex distribution. `tcolorbox` is more powerful in things like this.

Comment: I have only `basic-miktex` it takes a long time and installs all packages by downloading during **compilation** so I went back to `texlive` @HarishKumar

Comment: No problem with MikTeX and last `tcolorbox`. Probably your system doesn't use last `tcolorbox`. Could you show us what `\listfiles` do you use? Did you try with downloaded package installed in working directory? (Not good practice but can help here)

Comment: @Ignasi please see my edited question

Comment: As you can see in file list, you're using tcolorbox 2.22 (2013/05/15). CTAN version is 2.80 (2014/03/31). Although you've downloaded it, latex is using the old one. I don't know TeXLive, so I cannot help you to solve this problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because looking at the comment above, it seems that the issue at hand can be resolved by updating the TeX-distribution.