# Customizing this titlepage's vertical spacing

Tags: titles

Recently I've found this post where users were showing awesome titlepages:

[Showcase of beautiful title page done in TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85904/showcase-of-beautiful-title-page-done-in-tex/85989#85989)

I've tried to make a small adjustment on putting the website (as in the picture) on the bottom of the page but I couldn't. Would anybody help me to achieve that?

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\definecolor{titlepagecolor}{cmyk}{1,.60,0,.40}
\definecolor{namecolor}{cmyk}{1,.50,0,.10}

%-----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
    % ----------------------------------------------------------------
    \begin{titlepage}
        \newgeometry{left=5cm} %defines the geometry for the titlepage
        \pagecolor{titlepagecolor}
        \noindent
        \includegraphics[width=3cm]{logo.png}\\[-2 em]
        \color{white}
        \makebox[0pt][l]{\rule{1.3\textwidth}{1pt}}
        \par
        \noindent
        \Large \textbf{\textsf{Differential Equations}} %\hspace{0.1cm} \textcolor{namecolor}{\textsf{Material didático}}
        \vfill
        \noindent
        {\huge \textsf{1 - Big Topic}}
        \vskip\baselineskip
        \noindent
        \par
        \textsf{1.1 - Subtopic}
        \vskip\baselineskip
        \noindent
        \vskip\baselineskip
        \begin{center}
            \textsf{www.website.com}
        \end{center}

    \end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that?

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\definecolor{titlepagecolor}{cmyk}{1,.60,0,.40}
\definecolor{namecolor}{cmyk}{1,.50,0,.10}

%-----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
    % ----------------------------------------------------------------
{ \begin{titlepage}
        \newgeometry{left=5cm, bottom = 1cm} %defines the geometry for the titlepage
 \pagecolor{titlepagecolor}
        \noindent
        \includegraphics[width=3cm]{logo.png}\\[-2 em]
        \color{white}
        \makebox[0pt][l]{\rule{1.3\textwidth}{1pt}}
        \par
        \noindent
        \Huge \textbf{\textsf{Differential Equations}} %\hspace{0.1cm} \textcolor{namecolor}{\textsf{Material didático}}
        \vfill
        \noindent
        {\huge \textsf{1 -- Big Topic}}
        \vskip\baselineskip
        \noindent
        \par
        \LARGE\textsf{1.1 -- Subtopic}
 \vskip\baselineskip
 \noindent
 \vskip\baselineskip
\vfill
 \begin{center}
 \textsf{www.website.com}
 \end{center}
    \end{titlepage}}

 \newpage

 Blahblah
 \pagecolor{white}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's perfect Bernard, thank you. Best Regards!

Comment: How to make sections and chapters similar to this style?

Comment: A lot of things can be done with the `titlesec` package, but could you describe more precisely what you'd like to have?