# Title page rendering incorrectly

Tags: horizontal-alignment, titles, rendering

I'm using a standard template for my title page of my document as found at the [latex wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation#A_practical_example)

However, for some reason, the minipage on the right, with my supervisor's information, renders about one inch left of where it should.

I wonder if anyone can help me with this. Here's my source:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}
\raggedright
\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
        \textsc{\LARGE University of Blah} \\
        \vspace{1cm}
        \textsc{\Large School of Egg Decoration} \\
        \vspace{0.8cm}
        \rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm} \\[0.35cm]
        \bfseries{\huge On the decoration of Ostrich Eggs}
        \rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}
    \end{center}
    \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
        \begin{flushleft}
            \emph{Author:} \\
            \textsc{Edward Eggman} \\
            \url{E.Eggman@ublah.edu}
        \end{flushleft}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
        \begin{flushright}
            \emph{Supervisor:} \\
            \textsc{Dr James Eggthusiast} \\
            \url{J.Eggthusiast@ublah.edu}
        \end{flushright}
    \end{minipage} \\
    \vfill
    \begin{center}
    \large \emph{30\textsuperscript{th} June 2015}
    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}
% document content here
\end{document}
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. For your problem, you have two minipages with 40 % width which are just separated by a white-space. Just end the first minipage with `\end{minipage}\hfill` in order to get the second minipage flushed right.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi I think that the `\raggedright` before the `\begin{titlepage}` doesn't help. There seems to be no reason to have it before the `titlepage` instead of after it.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi I'll definitely have a read of the starter guide, sorry for my poor etiquette. And your solution worked perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use an `\hfill` to force space between the minipages

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
        \textsc{\LARGE University of Blah} \\
        \vspace{1cm}
        \textsc{\Large School of Egg Decoration} \\
        \vspace{0.8cm}
        \rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm} \\[0.35cm]
        \bfseries{\huge On the decoration of Ostrich Eggs}
        \rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}
    \end{center}
    \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
        \begin{flushleft}
            \emph{Author:} \\
            \textsc{Edward Eggman} \\
            \url{E.Eggman@ublah.edu}
        \end{flushleft}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
        \begin{flushright}
            \emph{Supervisor:} \\
            \textsc{Dr James Eggthusiast} \\
            \url{J.Eggthusiast@ublah.edu}
        \end{flushright}
    \end{minipage} \\
    \vfill
    \begin{center}
    \large \emph{30\textsuperscript{th} June 2015}
    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\raggedright

% document content here
\end{document}
```

[image]

And for some other nice examples of title pages: [Showcase of beautiful title page done in TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85904/showcase-of-beautiful-title-page-done-in-tex)

Answer (score 4):

Rather than use a minipage and have to guess the width, usually better to use a `tabular` and allow each box to be its natural width, so you can left align the text in the box but set the box flush right.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}
\raggedright
\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
        \textsc{\LARGE University of Blah} \\[1cm]
        \textsc{\Large School of Egg Decoration} \\[0.8cm]
        \rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm} \\[0.35cm]
        \bfseries{\huge On the decoration of Ostrich Eggs}
        \rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}
    \end{center}

        \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
            \emph{Author:} \\
            \textsc{Edward Eggman} \\
            \url{E.Eggman@ublah.edu}
        \end{tabular}\hfill
        \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
            \emph{Supervisor:} \\
            \textsc{Dr James Eggthusiast} \\
            \url{J.Eggthusiast@ublah.edu}
        \end{tabular}
    \par
    \vfill
    \begin{center}
    \large \emph{30\textsuperscript{th} June 2015}
    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}
% document content here
\end{document}
```