# How to Decrease Picture Height in Tikz

Tags: titles

This mwe comes from this post [Showcase of beautiful title page done in TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85904/showcase-of-beautiful-title-page-done-in-tex) (2nd example). The picture's height (blue fill) is 0.5 of the page.
How can we change the ratio to, say, 0.2 or 0.3 of the cover page's height?
I have searched several posts and tried different alternatives like changing the \newgeometry and \path options but was unable to find a solution. Thanks.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[some]{background}

\definecolor{mycolor}{cmyk}{1,.60,0,.40}
\backgroundsetup{
scale=1,
angle=0,
opacity=1,
contents={\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
 \path [fill=mycolor](current page.west)rectangle(current page.north east); 
\end{tikzpicture}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\BgThispage
\newgeometry{left=1cm,right=6cm,bottom=2cm}
\vspace*{0.3\textheight}
\noindent

\begin{minipage}{0.63\linewidth}
\vspace{5pt}
   \end{minipage}
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After adding the `calc` library, you can set the ratio using `$(current page.north west)!.3!(current page.south west)$` to get the blue rectangle height as 0.3 of the page height, for example.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[some]{background}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\definecolor{mycolor}{cmyk}{1,.60,0,.40}
\backgroundsetup{
scale=1,
angle=0,
opacity=1,
contents={\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
 \path [fill=mycolor]($(current page.north west)!.3!(current page.south west)$)rectangle(current page.north east); 
\end{tikzpicture}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\BgThispage
\newgeometry{left=1cm,right=6cm,bottom=2cm}
\vspace*{0.3\textheight}
\noindent

\begin{minipage}{0.63\linewidth}
\vspace{5pt}
   \end{minipage}
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

> [image]