# Playing with cover page style

Tags: color, templates, covers

I am newbie in making beautiful, "complex" latex covers and I need your help. 
I have the following very simple cover page but I will really like to make it look (as a structure) like this [nice structure](https://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C1GGRV_enGB764GB764&biw=1920&bih=969&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=ZkjwW5LXE6mSlwTKg7qABg&q=picard%20allometric&oq=picard%20allometric&gs_l=img.3...3984.5634..5787...0.0..0.62.545.10......1....1..gws-wiz-img.......0j0i30j0i8i30j0i24.m7Ltwlcerpc#imgdii=XrlsFicbrb25CM:&imgrc=DPRCJW_TartKuM:). I have seen [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85904/showcase-of-beautiful-title-page-done-in-tex) which is a very good start for me to explore different styles I want something similar to the example.

does anyone knows a similar template?

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e,booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{tabularx}



\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\pagestyle{fancy}

%\fancyhf{}
\lhead{}

\makeatletter
\def\thanks#1{\protected@xdef\@thanks{\@thanks
        \protect\footnotetext{#1}}}
\makeatother
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{$\displaystyle}c<{$}}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\begin{document}
    \title{\vspace{-3.0cm}\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}\\My title here\\\vspace{1.0cm}\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}\\{\Large Report}}
    \author{my name\thanks{my school}}

    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you started.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{titling}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{%
  \gdef\@subtitle{#1}}
\newcommand{\@subtitle}{}

\renewcommand{\maketitlehooka}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0pt]
    \node (image) [anchor=north] at (current page.north)
      {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=0.9\paperheight]{%
         example-image.jpg}};
    \fill [blue!60!black, opacity=0.7] (current page.north west) rectangle
      ([yshift=-0.3\paperheight]current page.north east)
      node (title) [text=white, opacity=1.0, text width=17cm, align=flush center,
        font=\sffamily\Huge\bfseries] at (current path bounding box.center)
        {\@title};
    \node (subtitle) [text=white, font=\sffamily\huge\bfseries, below=of title]
      {\@subtitle};
    \shade [top color=black, bottom color=brown] (image.south west) rectangle
      (current page.south east)
        node (logo) [xshift=-1cm, anchor=east]
          at (current path bounding box.east)
          {\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a.jpg}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \title{}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\title{Manual de construcción de ecuaciones alométricas para estimar el
volumen y la biomasa de los árboles}
\subtitle{Del trabajo de campo a la predicción}
\author{}
\date{}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: thank you. Your way is very simple but I have just one question. After testing different colours and images I haven't managed to remove the lines from the grey part. With which part of your code can I do this?

Comment: @geo_dd The background image is `example-image.jpg` and the logo is `example-image-a.jpg`. You can replace them with whatever you want. If you want a solid blue colour so you can't see through it, then remove the two `opacity` options.

Comment: thanks! with the opacity I have already changes the blue colour but I was just wondering about the lines in grey part. Thank you!