# Showcase of beautiful chapter designs

Tags: book-design

I'm currently writing a book, and I was wondering if you guys could display your chapter designs:

- Complex - have different formatting
- Beautiful and awesome
- With the tex source code
- Nothing original. Something you've made/customized

I have seen the chapters from the `memoir` class, but I would like something that's custom-made and not from a class.

I think this would be very motivational and inspiring stuff!

Here's my chapter design:

```tex
\documentclass[headinclude,footinclude,openany]{scrbook}
\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers,pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{arsclassica}
\usepackage{changepage}

\strictpagecheck

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]%
        {\normalfont\Large\sffamily}%
        {{\color{halfgray}\chapterNumber\thechapter%
        \hspace{10pt}\vline}  }{10pt}%
        {\spacedallcaps}[\chapterdecoration]

\definecolor{halfgray}{gray}{0.55}

\newcommand\anglei{-45}
\newcommand\angleii{45}
\newcommand\angleiii{225}
\newcommand\angleiv{135}

\newcommand\chapterdecoration{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,shorten >= -10pt]
\coordinate (aux1) at ([yshift=-15pt]current page.north east);
\coordinate (aux2) at ([yshift=-410pt]current page.north east);
\coordinate (aux3) at ([xshift=-4.5cm]current page.north east);
\coordinate (aux4) at ([yshift=-150pt]current page.north east);
\checkoddpage
\ifoddpage
\else
\coordinate (aux1) at ([yshift=-15pt]current page.north west);
\coordinate (aux2) at ([yshift=-410pt]current page.north west);
\coordinate (aux3) at ([xshift=4.5cm]current page.north west);
\coordinate (aux4) at ([yshift=-150pt]current page.north west);
\renewcommand\anglei{-135}
\renewcommand\angleii{135}
\renewcommand\angleiii{-45}
\renewcommand\angleiv{45}
\fi
\begin{scope}[halfgray!40,line width=12pt,rounded corners=12pt]
\draw
  (aux1) -- coordinate (a)
  ++(\angleiii:5) --
  ++(\anglei:5.1) coordinate (b);
\draw[shorten <= -10pt]
  (aux3) --
  (a) --
  (aux1);
\draw[opacity=0.6,halfgray,shorten <= -10pt]
  (b) --
  ++(\angleiii:2.2) --
  ++(\anglei:2.2);
\end{scope}
\draw[halfgray,line width=8pt,rounded corners=8pt,shorten <= -10pt]
  (aux4) --
  ++(\angleiii:0.8) --
  ++(\anglei:0.8);
\begin{scope}[halfgray!70,line width=6pt,rounded corners=8pt]
\draw[shorten <= -10pt]
  (aux2) --
  ++(\angleiii:3) coordinate[pos=0.45] (c) --
  ++(\anglei:3.1);
\draw
  (aux2) --
  (c) --
  ++(\angleiv:2.5) --
  ++(\angleii:2.5) --
  ++(\anglei:2.5) coordinate[pos=0.3] (d);   
\draw 
  (d) -- +(\angleii:1);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
  \mbox{}\newpage
  \mbox{}\newpage

  \chapter{Part 1: Introduction}
  \label{chap:part_1_introduction}
  
  \lipsum[1-4]
  
  % chapter part_1_introduction (end)
  
  \newpage

  \chapter{Part 2: Outline of this Book}
  \label{chap:part_2_outline_of_this_book}
  
  \lipsum[1-4]
  
  % chapter part_2_outline_of_this_book (end)
  
  \newpage
\end{document}
```

which makes this:

[image]

Comment: Presumably if you don't want it from a class you would also not want it from a package, so you want someone to do it for you. The `memoir` class does provide some chapter styles but it also shows the code for them as a help to enable you to create your own style. There is at least one other document/package showing/providing chapter styles. Do it yourself! --- GOM

Comment: No. I already have my own custom-made chapter design. I just want to see what other people have made!

Comment: @SingularisArt edit into your question your custom-made design and code if you have made one then so people do not view this as a "do-it-for-me" question which it 99.9999% is. There are already links on here and google searches that will show you chapter designs made with latex, maybe not with the code which is what it seems you want.

Comment: Take a look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85904/showcase-of-beautiful-title-page-done-in-tex. I got this idea from that link

Comment: @LaccaseTVersicolor I've updated the question showing my chapter design.

Comment: In my humble opinion, based on a limited experience, I can see a big gap between the **memoir** examples and _real_ fancy chapters as 
@SingularisArt (and me) wants to view, for review it and study it. And, precisely, break that gap is we want. It's not a "do-it-for-me" question! Not at all!

Comment: @karloswitt What is an acceptable "fancy chapter" is a matter of personal opinion. Perhaps you would like to demonstrate what you think is a "fancy chapter" as opposed to the many different styles of chapters that are in general use. -- GOM

Comment: Unfortunately your MWE does not produce the graphic you show as your MWE is missing at least two `\usepackage{...}` commands in the preamble. When you provide an MWE please try it out before posting it.

Comment: Peter Wilson, you are right. What I mean is that it is very difficult to see LaTeX source code with examples of chapter formats other than those that appear in the manual examples, not that they are not attractive.

Comment: Have you looked at the `fancychap` package?

Comment: @PeterWilson Yes. I have looked at the `fancychap` package.